# Why does Asp.NET WebApi render an IIS error page in response using ExceptionFilter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got the following exception filter:

```
public class ServiceLayerExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Result == null)
            {
                context.Result = new HttpResponseMessage();
            }

            context.Result.StatusCode = context.Exception.ConvertToHttpStatus();   
            base.OnException(context);
        }
    }
```

My ConvertToHttpStatus() is just an extension which looks up a Dictionary object of exception types which map to HttpStatusCodes.  The http status code is being converted correctly.  However in the response payload I get an IIS error page.  Preferably I'd like to have the response empty or even better have the exception message passed as json. Does anyone know why I'm getting an IIS error page returned and how to return empty or valid content?

Comment: What was the `Accept` header? Is it `beta` or *nightly build*?

Comment: It is beta build using NuGet package.  Accept header in request is: Accept:*/*

Comment: so what is the problem? you are accepting everything and systems sends you HTML. Use `accept:application/json` and that should send you JSON response.

Comment: Added this line in the filter: context.Result.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");  but this has no effect. Still get stack trace from IIS in response payload...Not sure if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Try http://forums.asp.net/post/4900693.aspx, also check this thread - http://forums.asp.net/t/1776405.aspx/1

Comment: FWIW - ACCEPT seems to be only a REQUEST header not a valid RESULT/RESPONSE header.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't write any content to the HTTP response message that you created. Try adding some content:

```
public class ServiceLayerExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        message.CreateContent(typeof(Foo), new Foo { Bar = "baz" });
        context.Result = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I was missing!